# cart.html is not working in Django and code is not executing

Tags: loops

My for loop is not working and it is not returning any images and data. I think there is any logical mistake over it.

views.py code
def cart(request):

```
  if request.user.is_authenticated:
     customer = request.user.customer
     order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
     items = order.orderitem_set.all()
  else:
     items = []    

  context = {'items':items}
  return render(request,'app/cart.html',context)
```

cart.html

{% for item in items %}

{{item.product.product}}

{{item.product.prize}}

```
                <div style="flex:1; margin-left:140px">
                    <p class="quantity">{{item.quantity}}</p>
                    <div class="quantity">
                        <img  class="chg-quantity update-cart" src="{% static  'images/arrow-up.png' %}">
                        <img class="chg-quantity update-cart" src="{% static  'images/arrow-down.png' %}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="flex:1; margin-left:170px;"><p>$23</p></div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

Please solve it. I spend a lot of time on it, but I couldn't solve as I am new to Django